# Google earth dependancy problems

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, google-earth

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglu1-mesa:i386 is already the newest version.
libglu1-mesa:i386 set to manually installed.
libsm6:i386 is already the newest version.
libsm6:i386 set to manually installed.
libx11-6:i386 is already the newest version.
libx11-6:i386 set to manually installed.
libfontconfig1:i386 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
libglib2.0-0:i386 set to manually installed.
libxext6:i386 is already the newest version.
libxext6:i386 set to manually installed.
libxrender1:i386 is already the newest version.
libxrender1:i386 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.



:~$  sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-earth-stable : Depends: ia32-libs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: OK, try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before you do this.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Same as above .

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Arg, I hate this problem.  Try `sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 unity-control-center` and then try `sudo apt-get install --recommends google-earth-stable`

Comment: sudo apt-get install --recommends google-earth-stable
E: Command line option --recommends is not understood

Comment: Then remove --recommends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386


 Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
                        Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
```

&

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1710

Comment: Umm, are you using Mint Linux?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Mint is off-topic here.

Comment: i use ubuntu 14.04 lts 64bit

Comment: OK, just checking